# AngularJS POST with $resource sending in query string, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, post

I'm a bit of a noob with Angular and am having issues trying to post to a Drupal Services endpoint. I can post just fine with HttpRequester (FFox plugin), however all my attempts with Angular to post data to get a session result in 401 Unauthorized: missing required argument username or other errors.

Here is my testing factory resource with default input:

```
    userInfoApp.factory('LoginService', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/auth-service/user/login', {username: 'admin', password: 'admin'}, {
        update: {
          method: 'POST', // this method issues a POST request
          headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }
      });
    });
```

Here is the call I am making to it inside the controller (this):

```
    this.login = function() {
       var login = LoginService.update(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
       });
    };
```

So far this usually results in a query string generated like so:

http://project.loc/auth-service/user/login?password=admin&username=admin

and the response of:

401 Unauthorized : Missing required argument username

What might I be doing wrong here? I have gotten $resource to work just fine with other endpoints (like for a menu service to retrieve a menu) however posting seems to be much more finicky. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: your $resource config seems to be using POST method.. and your URL have querystring? can you check if your Drupal Services endpoint can get those params? I believe your Drupal Services debug will not get the params!

Comment: No the service cannot get the params. And in fact, I wouldn't want it to. I want the POST to actually post. Login should not happen on the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a way that works; for the controller function:

```
    this.login = function() {
      var data = {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
      };
      var login = LoginService.save({}, data, 
        function(data) {
          // possibly do stuff with result
        },
        function(reply) {
          // Comments on best way to access $scope here are welcome.
          //  This feels a bit weird to me.
          $scope.info.errorMessage = reply.statusText;
        }  
      );
    };
```

And for the factory service:

```
      // Login factory service
      userInfoApp.factory('LoginService', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/auth-service/user/login');
      });
```

This actually retrieves the session id and other user data from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Your current configuration for $resource sends username & password as querystring. Hence they appear in your URL. I assume you need these values to be POST.

According to documentations all non GET methods have a payload parameter in the `action` method:

> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData,
>   [success], [error])

What you need to do is stop sending the parameters as default `[parameters]` and make use of the `postData` to POST data to your Drupal Services endpoint. You could do this when you call `$update()` as:

```
LoginService.update({}, {username: "admin",password: "admin"});
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't do it. Changed the service call to: this.login = function() { var login = LoginService.update({}, {username: "admin", password: "admin"}); }; And it had no impact.